# how to hide timespinner using javascript

Tags: javascript, xslt

I have xsl file below:

```
<td class="field" width="20%">
<input id="starttime" name="starttime" class="easyui-timespinner" style="width:80px;" required="required" data-options="min:'08:30',showSeconds:false" />
</td>
```

How I can disable or hide the time spinner when option is select?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have forgotten to add in the option picker but this is usually handled via adding a 'hidden' css class

https://jsfiddle.net/9g1L5f64/

JS

```
document.getElementById('mySelect').addEventListener('change', function hideSpinner(){
    document.getElementById('spinner').classList.add('hidden');
})
```

CSS

```
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you want but here goes.
I don't know how you'll recognize the option is selected, but when you do you can call a Javascript function to hide it. Something like

```
<script>
function hideSpinner() {
    document.getElementById('starttime').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

You can also set the visibility instead, but the results will be basically the same:

```
<script>
function hideSpinner() {
    document.getElementById('starttime').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
</script>
```

Finally, you can use JQuery instead and do it like

```
<script>
function hideSpinner() {
    $('#starttime').hide();
}
</script>
```

You can combine each of these with an if statement to simply toggle between visibility/display states, or just JQuery's toggle() itself.
P.S.: Note that if you won't be using JQuery for much else, the time it takes to load the library probably isn't worth it.

Comment: f.starttime.value = "09:00";
f.endtime.value = "17:00";
document.getElementById('starttime').style.visibility = 'hidden'; i have try solution no 1 and 2, solution 1 the spinner visible at left side, solution 2 I cannot display the fix value of starttime.

Comment: Do you have more than one element to make the spinner? Only one is needed, but I mean, images and whatnot to make it more visually appealing or something.
Didn't quite get the second problem.

Comment: I want to display the value of start time but I don't want it to be change by click the up and down arrow of timespinner

Comment: Try document.getElementById('starttime').disabled = true; instead. It should still show the element but it won't let the user interact with it.